# How do I set the last sheet in a spreadsheet as active sheet using SpreadsheetApp.openById()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I set the last sheet in my spreadsheet to the active sheet? This code isn't working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
    var logbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my key code");

    var totalSheets = logbook.getNumSheets();
    var lastSheet = logbook.getSheets[totalSheets];
    var currentSheet = logbook.setActiveSheet(lastSheet);
```

I'm getting an error:

> Can not find method setActiveSheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this instead :

```
var logbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my key code");
var totalSheets = logbook.getNumSheets();
var lastSheet = logbook.getSheets()[totalSheets-1];// !! () and -1 because if 3 sheets, last sheet is [2]
var lastSheetName = lastSheet.getName();
var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(lastSheet);
```

that said, it seems complicated to access a single sheet... what I do usually is simply that :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);// ss for spreadsheet
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');// sh for sheet
```

that's pretty standard in a lot of example code...

Comment: I changed the code to var logbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my key code");
  
  var totalSheets = logbook.getNumSheets();
  var lastSheet = logbook.getSheets[totalSheets];
  var lastSheetName = lastSheet.getName();
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(lastSheetName);

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: Cannot call method "getName" of undefined.

Comment: So if I have my sheets named with the year (2012 for example) I would search for the year and choose the page that matches? If it doesn't exist then I would duplicate the current page and rename with the year?  I've had trouble duplicating sheets also. Doesn't seem to be able to do it.

Comment: I tried it again without the line that has var lastSheetName and it worked for some reason. I had tried it before and it didn't. Not sure what I did differently this time... Thanks for your help!

Comment: remove this line:
var lastSheetName = lastSheet.getName();